# Importing a custom font in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, fonts

I am trying to incorporate a custom font in my app. I am using Nova Solid created by Billy Argel.

I imported the font and set it in info.plist. When I set a label to the Nova Solid font it shows up on storyboard as the correct font:
[image: font is correct]

But when I run the app, the font displays as the default font:
[image: incorrect font when running app]

Every other font I import works fine, not sure if it's something with these specific fonts by Argel or something I'm doing. I will appreciate some insight/help.

This is my info.plist
[image]

Comment: Maybe would help if you showed your plist? Are you only dealing with setting the font from the storyboard (as opposed to in code)? Did you add the font as a target to your project? There's some other things to try in [this good article](https://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a chance that the font file isn't added as a target, try inspecting the file and making sure it is a target otherwise the font file won't be distributed with the app.

This is a common issue when the font works in IB but doesn't work in the simulator/on a device.

Comment: THANK YOU!! it wasn't added as a target